# KinectSensor NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, kinect, nullreferenceexception

A week ago, we had a working project. The following worked, without a problem on my machine (Window 8 developing in VisualStudio 2010)

```
KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
public KinectController()
    {
        sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += runtime_SkeletonFrameReady;
        sensor.ColorStream.Enable();
        sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
        sensor.Start();
    }
```

This worked no problems. When my teammate pulled this down from an SVN, it broke, giving a null reference exception on ColorStream.Enable(). Deleting and adding the Microsoft.Kinect reference, for some reason, fixed it in the past, but now, it seems as though it is broken permanently. I ALWAYS throws an exception at this line. In debug, the ColorStream and SkeletonStream are null, even though it was clearly instantiated. Even doing

```
KinectSensor sensor;
public KinectController()
    {
        sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
        sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += runtime_SkeletonFrameReady;
        sensor.ColorStream.Enable();
        sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
        sensor.Start();
    }
```

will throw the null reference exception. What is happening? Why is this throwing an exception? It broke just as we were ready to present it, which is disheartening to even program with Kinect again.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852736/kinect-error-enabling-stream) is it possible that you're pulling in the wrong `KinectSensor`? Try iterating the `KinectSensors` collection and finding the one that has its `Status` property is set to `Connected` and using that rather than assuming the first item in the list (the one at `[0]`) is the correct one to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. While I implemented the method, it didn't pick up the sensor. Also, I forgot to mention that my friend who pulled it down was using Windows 7 and from that computer committed to the SVN. Would this have corrupted it in any way?

Comment: Doubtful, especially if you're just using the SVN as a code repository and just rebuilding wherever you checkout a copy. From the question I linked to they even talk about just replugging it in several times until it magically detected and worked.