# Kinect avateering example error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, kinect

In the Kinect chooser class of the Kinect avateering c# sample , i always encounter this error " Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " any ideas why ? i'm wondering whether it is actually a problem with my kinect

```
public KinectChooser(Game game, ColorImageFormat colorFormat, DepthImageFormat depthFormat)
        : base(game)
    {
        this.colorImageFormat = colorFormat;
        this.depthImageFormat = depthFormat;

        this.nearMode = false;
        this.seatedMode = false;



        KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += this.KinectSensors_StatusChanged;
        this.DiscoverSensor();

        this.statusMap.Add(KinectStatus.Undefined, "Required");
        this.statusMap.Add(KinectStatus.Connected, string.Empty);
        this.statusMap.Add(KinectStatus.DeviceNotGenuine, "Device Not Genuine");
        this.statusMap.Add(KinectStatus.DeviceNotSupported, "Device Not Supported");
        this.statusMap.Add(KinectStatus.Disconnected, "Required");
        this.statusMap.Add(KinectStatus.Error, "Error");
        this.statusMap.Add(KinectStatus.Initializing, "Initializing...");
        this.statusMap.Add(KinectStatus.InsufficientBandwidth, "Insufficient Bandwidth");
        this.statusMap.Add(KinectStatus.NotPowered, "Not Powered");
        this.statusMap.Add(KinectStatus.NotReady, "Not Ready");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the SpriteBatch from the services.
    /// </summary>
    public SpriteBatch SharedSpriteBatch
    {
        get
        {
            return (SpriteBatch)this.Game.Services.GetService(typeof(SpriteBatch));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the selected KinectSensor.
    /// </summary>
    public KinectSensor Sensor { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the last known status of the KinectSensor.
    /// </summary>
    public KinectStatus LastStatus { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether near mode is enabled.
    /// Near mode enables depth between 0.4 to 3m, default is between 0.8 to 4m.
    /// </summary>


  private void DiscoverSensor()
    {
        // Grab any available sensor
        this.Sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault();

        if (null != this.Sensor)
        {
            this.LastStatus = this.Sensor.Status;

            // If this sensor is connected, then enable it
            if (this.LastStatus == KinectStatus.Connected)
            {
                // For many applications we would enable the
                // automatic joint smoothing, however, in this
                // Avateering sample, we perform skeleton joint
                // position corrections, so we will manually
                // filter when these are complete.

                // Typical smoothing parameters for the joints:
                // var parameters = new TransformSmoothParameters
                // {
                //    Smoothing = 0.25f,
                //    Correction = 0.25f,
                //    Prediction = 0.75f,
                //    JitterRadius = 0.1f,
                //    MaxDeviationRadius = 0.04f 
                // };
                this.Sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
                this.Sensor.ColorStream.Enable(this.colorImageFormat);
                this.Sensor.DepthStream.Enable(this.depthImageFormat);
                this.Sensor.SkeletonStream.EnableTrackingInNearRange = true; // Enable skeleton tracking in near mode

                try
                {
                    this.Sensor.Start();
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    // sensor is in use by another application
                    // will treat as disconnected for display purposes
                    this.Sensor = null;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.LastStatus = KinectStatus.Disconnected;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See [KinectSensor NullReferenceException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118753/kinectsensor-nullreferenceexception).

Comment: @CodeCaster, there are no answers there?

Comment: @Anar there are comments and links in there with more explanation. This question as is is unanswerable.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for the link but that doesn't seem to solve the issue either

Comment: @Japhet what do you mean by "that"? What did you do or try?

Comment: @CodeCaster i followed what suggestions they made to fixing it , ive also plugged and unplugged my kinect several times , but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Show the relevant code then and point out at what line you get the NullReferenceException.

Comment: @CodeCaster    i highlighted in bold the line where i get nullreferenceeception

Comment: Then `Sensor.DepthStream` is `null`. Please also show the code that assigns `this.Sensor`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have uploaded the code

Comment: I think the `DiscoverSensor()` method assigns `this.Sensor`, do you mind showing that also?

Comment: @CodeCaster i have added the Discoversensor() method on here now

Comment: As explained throug the link I posted in my first comment, `KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault()` doesn't have to be a connected, usable sensor. You have to loop through `KinectSensor.KinectSensors` to find the one you're looking for.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok thank you , so how would i rectify this ?

Comment: Something like `Sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Connected )`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Would i replace this with the code i have or just add it in ?